# Swift : UIPanGestureRecognizer delegate method not called

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing some weird issue, here is my code for registering pan gesture

```
    public func registerGesture(_ view: UIView) {

        self.gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture(_:)))
        self.gesture?.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        self.gesture?.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        self.gesture?.delegate = self

        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.gesture!)
}
```

`UIPanGestureRecognizer` delegate method is not get called.

```
extension PanGestureHandler : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

   public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
      guard let g = self.gesture else { return false }
      guard g.view is UIScrollView else { return false }
      return true
}

   public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy
    otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       return false
}
```

}

Instead, if i debug the code and print the line `self.gesture.delegate`, then the delegate method is getting called.

Every time i need to print the above line to work. Please help me, thanks

Comment: Where are you calling registerGesture method?

Comment: @PiotrBernad, thanks for your reply. I find the solution, i have created a  singleton sharedinstance for the class, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the above issue, i have fixed by adding below sharedinstace,

```
   static let sharedInstance : PanGestureHandler = {
    let instance = PanGestureHandler()
    return instance
    }()
```

And registering the pangesture for view by,

```
    let gestureInstance = PanGestureHandler.sharedInstance
    gestureInstance.registerGesture(self.view)
```